# Can't run pycparser: Needs ply.yacc?

Tags: python, yacc, pycparser

I downloaded [`pycparser`](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/blob/master/pycparser/c_parser.py) and ran `python setup.py install`, but whenever I try to run *anything*, I get:

```
...
    from .c_parser import CParser
  File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.2\lib\site-packages\pycparser\c_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    import ply.yacc
ImportError: No module named ply.yacc
```

What's wrong? I'm pretty sure I followed the Readme exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it depends on [ply](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/). Download and install, and you should be fine.

Comment: Argh, can't believe they didn't put that in the readme (unless I missed it)... I'm not at my computer right now but I'll test it when I get the chance, thanks. +1 :)

Comment: Looks like you missed it :) - http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/source/browse/README.txt#66

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, these days [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser) comes with PLY pre-packaged so it's no longer a pre-requisite. Just install `pycparser` and you're ready to go.

Comment: Why not add `ply` to `install_requires`? (assuming that overriding `install` with `cmdclass` is a post-install action). Also, the generated tables are in the distribution archive on PyPI, so it seems that `setup.py` doesn't need to run PLY (like Cython is [recommended not to](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#distributing-cython-modules) be called during installation).